# Create custom fields for Invoice in Dynamics 365 Sales

Tags: dynamic, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, custom-fields, dynamics-crm-online

Hello I'm new to Dynamics, and I'm interested if there is a way to add a custom fields inside Invoices entity. I have seen that there is a way to create a new entity inside Sales, but I need to еxpand the Invoices entity in particular since the other fields in there are useful for me.
[Creating a New Invoice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8PXu.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add custom fields inside any standard or custom entity in a Dynamics 365 / Power Apps instance.

This is the documentation link to check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/data-platform/create-edit-fields

Comment: Thank you Guido, I have already read this documentation and made a custom table with custom fields that I need, but I can't find a way to publish them into the Invoices entity in Dynamics 365 Sales

Comment: you need to add the invoice entity to your solution and add fields there, you can't directly carry over fields from an entity to another (there is an XrmToolBox tool also mentioned inside that link but I suggest to try first to create manually, to check if the result is ok first)